# Inventory Management DB Design

Tags: database-design

**strong text**I am putting together a small inventory management system and have some questions concerning the database design. What I was planning on doing was to have 3 tables, `items`, `bins` and `shelves`. `Item`s would be created and added to the table. When we have stock of an item it will be in a `bin` on a `shelf`. If we don't have stock the item will still be in the `items` table but it won't have a location or the location will be set to a value that indicates  no stock.

I started the `items` table but I wasn't quite sure how to create the relationship between all the tables. I believe a foreign key is what I would be looking for but I'm not sure on the proper way to implement it. I was thinking the following lay out for the tables but as I started coding it I realized this wouldn't work.

**UPDATE: In response to the answer I received this is the query I came up with. It's wrapped in Python so ignore that.**

```
db = 'inventory.sqlite'
(cur, con) = open_db(db)
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Items (item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, \
            sku TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, \
            title TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL 
            )")
close_db(con)

(cur, con) = open_db(db)
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Bins (bin_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, \
            name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)")
close_db(con)

(cur, con) = open_db(db)
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Shelves (shelf_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, \
            name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)")
close_db(con)

(cur, con) = open_db(db)
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Bin_Contents (bin_id INTEGER NOT NULL, \
            item_id INTEGER NOT NULL, \
            qty INTEGER NOT NULL, \
            CONSTRAINT PK_Bin_Contents PRIMARY KEY (bin_id, item_id), \
            FOREIGN KEY (bin_id) REFERENCES Bins (bin_id), \
            FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES Items (item_id) \
            )")
close_db(con)

(cur, con) = open_db(db)
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Shelf_Contents (shelf_id INTEGER NOT NULL, \
            bin_id INTEGER NOT NULL, \
            CONSTRAINT PK_Shelf_Contents PRIMARY KEY (shelf_id, bin_id), \
            FOREIGN KEY (shelf_id) REFERENCES Shelves (shelf_id), \
            FOREIGN KEY (bin_id) REFERENCES Bins (bin_id) \
            )")
close_db(con)
```

After writing that and looking at it I realized that wouldn't function the way I wanted it to. As I mentioned earlier I believe a foreign key is what I need but I'm not sure about the best way to implement it. I would like to be able to:

UPDATE: Will the above query create the DB/tables i need to do the following:

- Use the app to search for items and display where they are located
  and how many are in each location.
- Use a shelf/bin number to pull up the contents of that shelf/bin. For
  example the user selects `shelf_a` from a menu. All the `bins` in
  `shelf_a` are displayed. The user can select a bin and see it's
  contents.
- Perform basic management tasks. Add an item to a shelf/bin, remove
  some/all the quantity of an item from a shelf/bin, add new
  shelves/bins etc with out anything disappearing. Shelves are still
  there even they are empty same for bins, they are still there even
  when they are empty.

I don't need help with the queries themselves I just need to make sure the proper relationships are in place so when I write the queries the right info comes back.

Comment: can bins be moved between shelves?  can an item be in more than one bin (eg, if you have too much of something, might it be spread across two bins?)

Comment: @Joe At present we usually don't place items in more than one location but I don't that should be a limitation. And no `bins` would stay where they are. If an item has to move, it would be removed from it's current location and added to a new one.

Comment: then you might want a join table between the item table and the table to track bins.  (and it might make sense to call that one 'locations', or at least not call the bins table 'locations').  Join tables will slow down queries, but you won't be able to track items in more than one bin without it or allow duplicate skus in the items table.

Comment: @Joe Is this what you had in mind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: Yes ... it'd then have foreign keys to the tables it's joining.  Minimally, it's just foreign keys to the tables it's joining, but it might also have some attributes itself (eg, tracking how many of the item are in a given bin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you want to think about based on the nature of your items and how you store and track them.

**Are your items discrete or are they a commodity?**  The way you would track television sets, each of which has its own distinct serial number is different from how you might track boxes of nails.  If your SKUs are discrete you don't have a "quantity" field, instead you track individual items with an intersection table (as suggested by Joe).  Otherwise whether you need an intersection table depends on how many different SKUs can be on a shelf (see below).

**Is it important to track inventory movements?**  Do you need to see stock deliveries and shipments?  If so you might want to take a kind of double entry accounting approach, treating shelves like GL numbers.  If not, a simpler quantity per shelf may be sufficient.

**Can multiple SKUs share a shelf?**  If so, you need an intersection table.  If not, you can get by with a foreign key from `Shelf` to `Item`.

**Does every bin have at least one shelf?**  Your application (queries) will be much simpler if every bin has at least one shelf, such that you don't need to track inventory which is in a bin but has no applicable shelf information.

---

**EDIT:**

It's important to get the terminology clear. When you say "bin" you mean a box without a lid that sits on a shelf. In a lot of inventory situations, a "bin" is a space on a rack where you could put a skid or one or more shelves.

As long as we're clear, you want a hierarchy of SHELVES each of which has many BINS each of which can have many BIN_CONTENTS each of which is an intersection between BIN and ITEM and which has a quantity. Don't store quantity on your ITEM table, store it on the intersection table, that way you can have multiple bins of the same item, or even many different kinds of items, each in their own distinct bins or even multiple different items mixed within a bin, all on the same shelf.

Consider the following ERD:

[image: ERD]

Comment: We deal in strictly commodity items
The only movements I need to track are adding items to a location and removing them. We have a larger inventory system in place but it's quite cumbersome and slow. This system I'm working on would be primarily for items that arrive in our warehouse and go out to customer within a day or two so we need a more lightweight solution.
My ideal solution would be to have every item have a location like `shelf_bin`. A bin will always be on a shelf. They only come off to put things in or take them out and then they go right back in the same place.

Comment: @IanAuld - It's important to get the terminology clear.  When you say "bin" you mean a box without a lid that sits on a shelf.  In a lot of inventory situations, a "bin" is a space on a rack where you could put a skid or one or more shelves.  As long as we're clear, you want a hierarchy of `SHELVES` each of which has many `BINS` each of which can have many `BIN_CONTENTS` each of which is an intersection between `BIN` and `ITEM` and which has a `quantity`.  Don't store quantity on your `ITEM` table, store it on the intersection table, that way you can have multiple bins of the same item.

Comment: Yes what I mean is there will be `shelves` that all contain a number of `bins` and inside the bins there will be `bin_contents`. 

So to be clear what you are saying is I need a `shelves` table, a `bins` table, an `items` table and then a `bin_contents` table that is an intersection of an `item` and a `bin` and this is where I should keep the qty info. Do I have that correct?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect your previous comment. Update your answer with the info you gave me and I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @IanAuld - I've expanded my answer as you requested.  **NOTE**: You do _not_ want to use your `Shelf_Contents` table, unless you mean to allow a bin to sit on two shelves simultaneously!  It is enough to have the `Shelf_ID` on the `Bins` table.  Each bin sits on exactly one shelf but each shelf can hold many bins.

Comment: I included the extra table was I was worried if the bins were all named the same on each shelf (shelf A has bins 1 - 10, as does shelf B for example) it could get confusing.